# How to avoid nested maps loops while rendering JSX in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, react-hooks, jsx

I have recently started creating a react online menu project and I encountered a situation where I had to use nested map loops to render an array of array. Please find the code below for the rendering that I have written. Below that is the data variable being used to render this information.
This algorithm, though it does the job and in most real life applications won't cause the user's system to hang, but it is still O(n^2) complexity. How can this nested loop be avoided while still rendering the correct style and information?

The code I have used to render:

```
<div className="container-fluid">
    <div className="rajat-menu-wrapper">
        {items.map(item => 
            <div key={item.title}>
                <h1 className="rajat-menu-category-heading"><span>{item.title}</span></h1>
                {item.items.map(foodItem => <FoodCard key={foodItem.name} data={foodItem}/>)}
            </div>)}
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is the data:

```
const menuData = [
    {
        title: 'Pizzas',
        items: [
            {
                name: 'Onion Pizza',
                desc: 'Enjoy the delicious treat of onions with extra cheese over a classic hand tossed dough.'
            },
            {
                name: 'Capsicum Pizza',
                desc: 'Enjoy the delicious treat of capsicums with extra cheese over a classic hand tossed dough.'
            },
            {
                name: 'Tomato Pizza',
                desc: 'Enjoy the delicious treat of tomatoes with extra cheese over a classic hand tossed dough.'
            },
            {
                name: 'Olive Pizza',
                desc: 'Enjoy the delicious treat of olives with extra cheese over a classic hand tossed dough.'
            },
            {
                name: 'Golden Corn Pizza',
                desc: 'Enjoy the delicious treat of corns with extra cheese over a classic hand tossed dough.'
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Comment: why you need to remove?

Comment: Maybe don't have a nested loop?

Comment: Create 2 components, parent and child that way it looks cool. But if you want to removed nested loop that will be bad idea. Bcoz Json is like that

Comment: There nothing wrong about nested loop. Companies using more complex nested loop.

Comment: You can create an `<Item />` component that contains the `h1` and the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

Reducing time complexity is necessary where there exist iterations that have no contribution to the end result. In your case, every iteration is necessary to display your data. So you shouldn't worry about the time complexity of that. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> This algorithm [...] is still O(n^2) complexity.

No, if  corresponds to the total number of *objects* in your data structure, then this is not true.

We might have  top level objects, and *m* second-level objects. In your example, =1 and  =5, and =1+5=6. The outer `map` call will iterate  times, so that the inner `map` will be launched  times, making in total  iterations. So this is O(+) = O().

It would look different if we would have define  as the number of top level objects, and assume that **each** top-level object had  second level objects, giving a total of ² objects. Then, yes, the complexity is O(²), but that is necessary if you want to output something about ² objects... So, no matter how you look at it, the time complexity is not a problem.

Comment: Agreed. But theoretically, we cannot just assume the input to be the best input when considering the time complexity of the solution.

Comment: And I am not assuming that either. This is not the type of problem where you have "best" or "worst" case.